# Putting a Count function for a matrix, in a loop

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, function-construction, inequalities, counting

previously i had a doubt on how to assign different rows with certain values using a special function, which i later figured out by using the far more superior "DO" Loop. At present i have two matrices c and d as shown below

```
dv = 1/2;
c = ( {
    {0 dv, 0},
    {1 dv, 0},
    {2 dv, 0},
    {3 dv, 0}
   } );
d = ( {
    {0.11, 0},
    {0.35, 0},
    {0.17, 0},
    {0.99, 0}
   } );
Do[Do[c[[i, 2]] = 
    Count[{d[[j, 1]]}, Between[d[[j, 1]], {(i - 1)*dv, (i)*dv}]], {i, 
    1, 4}], {j, 1, 4}];
MatrixForm[c]
```

so the output is -`MatrixForm[{{0, 0}, {1/2, 0}, {1, 0}, {3/2, 0}}]` 
but it should have been

```
MatrixForm[{{0, 3}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 0}, {3/2, 0}}]
```

i suspect the problem is in the "Between" function(maybe it is not a good equivalent of saying x lies between this and that). How do i rectify my code to get the desired output?(output explained= as 0.11,0.35 and 0.17 are lesser than 0.5 they belong to the ith row 2nd column where i is 1. Similarly 0.99 belongs to the 2nd row as it is less than 2dv-> that is 1 .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal changes to your code: (1) To increment `c[[i, 2]]` you need to use  `c[[i, 2]] += ..` and (2) the second argument of `Count` should be a pattern:

```
Do[Do[c[[i, 2]] += Count[{d[[j, 1]]}, _?(Between[#, {(i - 1)*dv, (i)*dv}] &)], {i, 1,
     4}], {j, 1, 4}];

MatrixForm[c]
```

[image]

You can use `Boole[Between[...]]` instead of `Count[...]`:

```
Do[Do[c[[i, 2]] += Boole@Between[d[[j, 1]], {(i - 1)*dv, (i)*dv}], {i, 1, 4}], {j, 1, 4}];
```

Using a single do loop instead of two:

```
c = ({{0 dv, 0}, {1 dv, 0}, {2 dv, 0}, {3 dv, 0}});

Do[c[[i, 2]] = Count[d[[All, 1]], _?(Between[#, {(i - 1)*dv, (i)*dv}] &)], {i, 1, 4}]

c
```

> ```
>  {{0, 3}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 0}, {3/2, 0}}
> ```

Alternative ways to get the same result without loops:

```
MapIndexed[{#[[1]], Length@
 Select[Function[x, (#2[[1]] - 1)*dv <= x <= #2[[1]]*dv]][d[[All, 1]]]} &, c]

MatrixForm @ %
```

[image]

```
Transpose[{c[[All, 1]], 
  Table[Count[d[[All, 1]], _?(Between[#, {(i - 1)*dv, (i)*dv}] &)], {i, 4}]}]
```

> ```
>  {{0, 3}, {1/2, 1}, {1, 0}, {3/2, 0}}
> ```

etc...